# What are the different add-on types in G Suite?

Tags: gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon, gsuite-addons

What are the supported ways to customize G Suite apps like Gmail, Drive, Calendar, Docs, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview

Add-ons are defined by the application they extend (the host application). There are two primary types of add-ons: G Suite add-ons and editor add-ons.

G Suite add-ons are the newest generation of add-ons. The previous iteration, Gmail add-ons, provided desktop and mobile extensions of Gmail only, using interfaces built from an Apps Script widget library. G Suite add-ons add a number of new features and capabilities, including the ability to extend Gmail, Google Calendar, and Google Drive — all with a single add-on. Previously created Gmail add-ons now function as G Suite add-ons; you can upgrade your Gmail add-on to take advantage of the new G Suite capabilities.

Editor add-ons are the extend one of the Google Drive editor host applications:

- Google Sheets
- Google Docs
- Google Slides
- Google Forms

G Suite add-ons and editor add-ons differ in how authorization is handled and how their interfaces are constructed. See Add-on types for more information.

Comment: If there is any publicly available timeline when/whether Google plans to "transform" editor addons into G Suite addons?